# VBA search sheet to fill userform

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use a find function that will find answers on a sheet and fill my userform. This will eliminate the need to be able to have to really look at the sheet. It has become more of it's own application.

I get an error at the:

```
    JobTitle.value = cF.Offset(0,1).value
```

Is there a better way to do this? I've tried creating a variable for both sides and neither seems to work. The error is:

> Object variable or With block variable not set

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

    JobTitle.Visible = True
    Label2.Visible = True
    Label3.Visible = True
    Label4.Visible = True
    Label5.Visible = True
    Label6.Visible = True
    TextBox1.Visible = True
    TextBox2.Visible = True
    TextBox3.Visible = True
    TextBox4.Visible = True

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets(" MthruF Schedule")

    ws.Activate
    Dim PartNumber As Variant
    PartNumber = SearchBar.Value

    'InputBox("Please Enter Requisition Number", "Information")

    Dim FirstAddress As String, cF As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(" MthruF Schedule").Range("A:A")
        .Cells(1, 1).Activate
        'First, define properly the Find method
        Set cF = .Find(What:=PartNumber, _
                       after:=ActiveCell, _
                       LookIn:=xlValues, _
                       LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                       SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                       SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                       MatchCase:=True, _
                       SearchFormat:=False)

        JobTitle.Value = cF.Offset(0, 1).Value
        TextBox1.Value = cF.Offset(0, 8).Value
        TextBox2 = cF.Offset(0, 9).Value
        TextBox3 = cF.Offset(0, 10).Value
        TextBox4 = cF.Offset(0, 13).Value

        'If there is a result, keep looking with FindNext method
        If Not cF Is Nothing Then
            FirstAddress = cF.Address
            Do
                Set cF = .FindNext(cF)
                'Look until you find again the first result
            Loop While Not cF Is Nothing And cF.Address <> FirstAddress
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Am guessing it errors because the part number is not found and so cF is Nothing and cannot be offset. You need to check first that it's found.

Comment: Having now seen all your code, just move those lines after `If Not cF Is Nothing Then`.

Comment: To further clarify, those five lines need to go inside the Do loop before the FindNext line.

Comment: SJR, That worked perfectly, Thank you so much. If I had more points and you posted an answer, I'd let you know yours was the best.